# What is AUTH-TOKEN for the Google Cloud Messaging(GCM)?

Tags: google-cloud-messaging, pushsharp

I have found library PushSharp for asp.net MVC 5 and a sample for using GCM.

```
var config = new GcmConfiguration ("GCM-SENDER-ID", "AUTH-TOKEN", null);
```

As I understood GCM-SENDER-ID is App ID from goodle console. But what is AUTH-TOKEN? I tried to use api key, but sample throws "wrong authentification" exception.
   I found some tutorial on the net and somebody have the same quation https://recordnotfound.com/PushSharp-Redth-3794

Answer (score 2):

Go to the firebase console for your app.

Click the Settings "gear" button to the right of the project name in the navigation - that will bring up a context menu.

Click "Project Settings".

Then in the navigation click "Cloud Messaging".

The AUTH-TOKEN is the server key listed under Project keys.